# Substitute/Alternative for UNION with single JOIN Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, union

I've a table called `posts` and i want to `retrieve` all the `records` which satisfies the below conditions in `select statement` and return a `single table` -

```
select ID from posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1
select ID from posts where ParentID in (select ID from posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1)
```

Now, by using `UNION` operator like below i can return a single table -

```
select ID from posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1
UNION 
select ID from posts where ParentID in (select ID from posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1)
```

**Output**

[image]

Tried below `JOIN` query but did not get the expected result and returns `NULL`-

```
select ID from posts cs
LEFT JOIN posts cs1 ON cs.ID = cs1.ID
where cs.UserID = 23487 and cs.PostLevel <>1 and cs.ParentID = cs1.ID
```

**Expected**

I want to fetch the records using `JOIN` OR using a single `SELECT` and not `UNION` to get the desired output as shown above.

Comment: `Union` and `Join` are two different things.. Why want to do this using `Join` ? I would go with one of below solutions, if you looking for optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just ORing together both conditions in a single `WHERE` clause:

```
select ID
from posts
where
    (UserID = 23487 and postlevel <> 1) or
    (ParentID in (select ID from cs_posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1))
```

Comment: returns 25 rows, should return 27

Comment: `UNION ALL` is preserving duplicates, which won't be generated in this join approach.  If your `UNION` query is working and performant, then why not use it?

Comment: Yes, right! `UNION ALL` was returning duplicate records, Thanks! Marked as a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select ID
from posts
where
    (UserID = 23487 and postlevel <> 1) or
    (EXISTS (select 1 from cs_posts where UserID= 23487 and postlevel <> 1 and ID = ParentID) )
```

Comment: returns only 24 rows, as per union query it should return 27

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary union or in or exists.... Try this :

```
select distinct F1.id from post F1 inner join
 posts f2 on f2.UserID= 23487 and f2.postlevel <> 1 AND 
(F1.id=f2.id or F1.parentid=f2.id)
```

If you want keep duplicate values remove the distinct